# Gitlab masked and protected variables preventing deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I am using `Gitlab` `CI/CD`. When using the `amazon/aws-cli:latest` image, the masked and protected variables `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` are preventing deployment. I know this because I unmasked and unprotected them and the deployment went through. How can I get the command to accept the masked and protected variables?

The error I am getting is

> An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Yaml file below:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws --version
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
    - aws configure set region "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
    - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name lambda-function --zip-file fileb://"$CI_PROJECT_NAME".zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected variables are only available on protected branches. So, if protecting your variable makes your job fail, it's probably because you're not running the job on a protected branch. You should also make sure you have not environment-scoped your variable (or if you have, that you specify the environment in your job definition)

Masking should have no impact on this.